# asp.net core controller not authorize with jwt

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` Library for jwt authentication in `ASP.Net Core Web Api`.When i request a token, it work fine and i get a token.
But when i send request to secure `Action` i get 401 status code.

in my `Startup` Class:

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> siteSettings)
    {
        var jwtOption = siteSettings.Value.JwtOption;
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtOption.Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtOption.Audience,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseApiCustomIdentityServices();
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Audience = jwtOption.Audience,
            Authority = jwtOption.Audience,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
        });
    }
```

And my `TokenController`:

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly IJwtService _jwtService;
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> _siteSettings;
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _serializerSettings;

    public TokenController(
        IUserManager userManager,
        IJwtService jwtService,
        IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> siteSettings
    )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _jwtService = jwtService;
        _siteSettings = siteSettings;
        _serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();
        var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(model.Username, model.Password);
        if (identity == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var response = new
        {
            id = identity.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id").Value,
            auth_token = await _jwtService.GenerateEncodedToken(model.Username, identity),
            expires_in = (int)_siteSettings.Value.JwtOption.ValidFor.TotalSeconds
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, _serializerSettings);
        return new OkObjectResult(json);
    }

    private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetClaimsIdentity(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            var userToVerify = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

            if (userToVerify != null)
            {
                if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(userToVerify, password))
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(_jwtService.GenerateClaimsIdentity(userName, userToVerify.Id.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        return await Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
    }
```

what's wrong?

Comment: If you haven't already, decode your token [here](https://jwt.io/) and double check it includes all the required claims

Comment: You should also move your call to `app.UseMvc` to be after the call to `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/))

Comment: I check decode token and it verified and move `app.UseMvc` after the call `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication` but still there is problem.

Comment: As a next step you could check the debug output in case in provides any more detail, then I would try relaxing the `JwtBearerOptions` in case one of them is the cause

Comment: I think found problem. when i creating token get the value of `SigningCredentials` and set in `JwtSecurityToken`, it is null.but why?

Comment: `SigningCredentials` are used by the server to create the encrypted "signature" part of the token. The decoder [here](https://jwt.io/) will let you know if the signature is being generated correctly (enter your server's secret plain-text key in the "secret" texbox in the "decoded" pane).